# My function to find the sum of the digits of twice of every other number entered is not working in C?

Tags: c, function

As the title says I'm trying to find the sum of the digits of twice every other digit in a number entered into the function. The first digit will be the second to last. For example, entering 58423 should return 2*2 (4), 8*2 (16-> 1+6 = 7) -- >4+7 = 11. Mine isn't working like that at all and seems to return random numbers. The function is below.

I'm using the fact that n % 10 will get you the rightmost digit of n, and (n / 10) % 10 will get you the next rightmost digit of n, and so on where n is the number entered.

```
int everyOther(long num) //(n / 10) % 10 will get you the next rightmost 
digit
{
    int incrementer = 1;
    int total = 0;
    long shifter = 1;
    int a = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        shifter = shifter *100;
        if(num/shifter == 0) 
        {
            break; // will have reached the end of the number if this is 
//true
        }
        a = 2* ((num / shifter) % 10); // every other digit right to left 
//starting from the second to last, multiplied by two
        total = total + (a/10 + a%10); //sum of the above product's 
//digits
        incrementer++;

    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Add logs of logging to your program so that it outputs what it's doing and what the previous and new values are. Then you can see exactly where it goes off the rails.

Comment: Or use a debugger, it's easier when you're learning programming (especially in C).

Comment: Curious, what result is expected with `everyOther(-42)`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs.

First, you only want to do `shifter = 100 * shifter;` once per loop. On each iteration, you want `shifter` to be 100 times what it was on the previous iteration. So just multiply by 100 once. You can get rid of `incrementer`. It's redundant.

Second, your example shows adding the digits of the 16 to get 7. But for some reason you commented out the code to do that.

```
int everyOther (long num)
{
    int shifter = 1; // dividing by 10 gets us the hundreds digit
    int total = 0;
    int a = 0;
    while (num/shifter > 0)
    {

        shifter *= 100; // move two digits over
        if(num/shifter == 0) 
          {
              break;  
          }
        a = 2 * ((num / shifter) % 10);
        total += (a/10 + a%10);

    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Note: `shifter *= 100;` may overflow.

Comment: The mix of `int` and `long` variables is a bit puzzling.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you! I've edited the code above to reflect the changes but unfortunately I'm still not getting the correct output. Is there anything else you see that's incorrect by any chance

Comment: @Elmer Add lots of logging to your code to see where it's going wrong.